# Typescript best way for changing API response / request values

Tags: typescript

We are at the moment building an angular application with the use of typescript. We are trying to be so strict as possible with typescript. The application makes a request to an API that does response with an object (type Holiday). In this object there is a datestring. This has to be a Date object in our application, because we are working with that.

First I was making two different interfaces. One for the API and one for in the application self. Like `response.map<APIHoliday, Holiday>(apiHoliday => ....)`.

One of our first methods was also changing it from a object, then mapped it and changing it then to a Holiday type. This was in our eyes not the best way, because no one know what for a type of object it was.

What is the best way when working with Types / Interfaces and API responses / requests?

Comment: What framework are you using (if any)? How are you receiving the data (fetch, xhr, rxJs, other)?

Comment: @ferikeem I've changed the question. But we're using angular & RXJS

Comment: I'm not that familiar with rxJS yet, but you can do `.pipe(map(response =>...))` (i assume you already use this). Also I'm not sure you can make it shorter/clearer than that (maybe deriving from HttpClient?). Or you can use an [interceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) and do the conversion there.

Comment: `.pipe(map(response =>...))` is the way to go when using map. But I'm now talking about the typescript typing around it and the cleanest way to achieve type mapping by an api request / response. Interceptors are nice, but the problem is that every http request is intercept by the interceptor, making it (in my eyes) to complex.

Comment: How many times do you have to use this mapping? If once or twice, I don't see the problem with the current approach, if many times, then an interceptor might be a good idea. Also it's not TypeScript types that are the problem, in plain javascript, you would have the same problem (runtime), because you are receiving a string from the API, and you want to use a Date object, which means you have to convert somewhere (again runtime).

Answer (score 0):

If you will have to use the mapping many times it can be useful to implement a date interceptor that will map the date string to a JS Date object (or a moment.js or luxon object if you are using those).

Example for the interceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class DateInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private dateParser: DateParserService) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        return next.handle(request.clone()).pipe(
            tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    const body = event.body;
                    this.dateParser.convertToDate(body);
                }
            })
        );
    }
}

export const DateInterceptorProvider = {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: DateInterceptor,
    multi: true,
};
```

Example for the date parse service:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DateParserService {
    myDateFormat = // Add the regex for your date string format here

    convertToDate(item: any) {
        if (item === null || item === undefined) {
            return item;
        }

        if (typeof item !== 'object') {
            return item;
        }

        for (const key of Object.keys(item)) {
            const value = item[key];
            if (this.isMyDateFormat(value)) {
                item[key] = this.convertMyDateFormatToDate(value);
            } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
                this.convertToDate(value);
            }
        }
    }

    private isMyDateFormat(value): boolean {
        if (value === null || value === undefined) {
            return false;
        }

        return this.myDateFormat.test(value);
    }

    private convertMyDateFormatToDate(date: string): Date {
        // Add the logic for the date conversion here
    }
}
```

Now add `DateInterceptorProvider` to the `providers` array of your module (e. g. `app.module.ts`)